# Mysql insert is not working on a trade script

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys and girls i own a rpg ( a online role playing game )
Were users can catch monsters and train them up and stuff. But now i have come around to building a trade script...

I show all there monsters and the other users monsters on the 1 page but when they pick what they want and what there offering for the monsters it will not add the info into the db...

So i have a page were they have to enter the users username they want to trade with.

```
    <form name="input" action="tradedo.php" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="username_trade" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then on tradedo.php there monsters are shown and the others users monsters are grab and they can pick what they want and what there offering for them...

```
    session_start();

mysql_connect("localhost", "blah", "");
mysql_select_db("");



$username_trade = $_POST['username_trade'];



$_SESSION['username_trade'] = $username_trade ;

echo "You put in id  ". $username_trade . ".<br />";



?>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="mid_box">
  <?php
                        // get and display userbox
                        $q = "SELECT id,pokemon,exp,level FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION['username_trade']."'";
                        $r = mysql_query($q);

                        if (mysql_num_rows($r) <= 0) {
                            echo "You have no current pokemon stored";

                        }
                    ?>

</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>
  <?php
 echo "<form action='tradestore.php' method='POST'>";
while ( $v = mysql_fetch_object( $r ) )
{
    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='pokemon[]' value='$v->dbid'/> They have a $v->pokemon    </label><br/>";
        echo "<label> Level $v->level     </label><br/>";
}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='user' value='$username_trade'/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Check!!'/>";
?>
</p>
<p><strong>Pick what you want two offer for the pokemon </strong></p>
<p>
  <?php
                        // get and display userbox
                        $q = "SELECT id,pokemon,exp,level FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION['username']."'";
                        $t = mysql_query($q);

                        if (mysql_num_rows($t) <= 0) {
                            echo "You have no current pokemon stored";

                        }
                    ?>
</p>
<p>


  <?php
 echo "<form action='test_process.php' method='POST'>";
while ( $v = mysql_fetch_object( $t ) )
{
    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='pokemonin[]' value='$v->dbid'/> I have a $v->pokemon</label><br/>";
    echo "<label> Level $v->level     </label><br/>";
}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='userin' value='$username'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

This works great .... It shows all the monsters and everything is great but now i need to insert them and here is the insert page

```
    session_start();

mysql_connect("localhost", "blahhhhhhhhhhh", "");
mysql_select_db("");



$pokemon = $_POST['pokemon'];
$pokemonin = $_POST['pokemonin'];
$meid = $_SESSION['username'];
$toid = $_POST['user'];
$dbid = array();
$dbid2 = array();

foreach ( $pokemon as $poke )
{   $dbid['pokemon'][] = $poke;

}

foreach ( $pokemonin as $poke2 )
{   $dbid2['pokemonin'][] = $poke2;


}




srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
$random_number = rand( );
echo "$random_number";


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO trade (trade_id, trade_to, trade_from, trade_pokeid, trade_mypokeid)
                            VALUES ('$random_number','".$toid."', '".$meid."', '".$dbid['pokemon']."', '".$dbid2['pokemonin']."');") or die("Error: ". mysql_error());



echo"Done";
```

In my db im getting

```
trade_id = 1977949793(works)
trade_to = 
trade_from = admin  (works)
trade_pokeid = Array ( no monster ids ???)
trade_mypokeid = Array( no monster ids ???)
```

Be for the script use to insert the monster id has 1,4,5,7  then id grab them and show them on a trade accept page.. but not its just adding Array and not even grabing the trade_to i have tryied to explain the best i can.

**And the db connect i have edited out .....**

Comment: There's something mighty familiar about all this... =]

Answer (score 1):

In your INSERT statement:

```
 ... '".$dbid['pokemon']."'
```

That's an array concatenated to a string and won't work.

You could serialize, or loop through it and create some representation, but it would be better to redesign the database scheme so you don't store multiple values in one field...

Comment: If you have to, you can use php'd implode and explode to break it into a string to store, and break that string back into an array after retrieving. And toid, are you sure it's being posted correctly?

Comment: Well the page works the one were it shows all the monsters just on the insert page it stops working..... There is 2 loops tho on the insert page....

Answer (score 1):

$dbid['pokemon'] and $dbid2['pokemonin'] are arrays, so when you concatenate them they turn to a string with value "Array".

Not regarding security or performance, this should work:

```
session_start();

mysql_connect("localhost", "blahhhhhhhhhhh", "");
mysql_select_db("");

$pokemon = $_POST['pokemon'];
$pokemonin = $_POST['pokemonin'];
$meid = $_SESSION['username'];
$toid = $_POST['user'];

foreach ( $pokemon as $poke )
{
    foreach ( $pokemonin as $poke2 )
    {
        srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
        $random_number = rand( );
        echo "$random_number";

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO trade (trade_id, trade_to, trade_from, trade_pokeid, trade_mypokeid)
    VALUES ('$random_number','".$toid."', '".$meid."', '".$poke."', '".$poke2."');") or die("Error: ". mysql_error());

    }
}

echo "Done";
```

Comment: Ok, I think I didn't understood what you wanted to do in first place! You want to offer to all the monsters in $pokemon all the offers in $pokemonin. Is that it?

Comment: yer i wanna store both of whats in them in trade_pokeid and trade_from